# Unity3D to Android: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex formatc

Tags: unity, c#, android

I could not get past the error below. I already tried finding duplicated plugins but there are none and I am still getting errors when building in Unity3d to an Android.

Plugins Used:

- FacebookSDK
- UTNotifications

Unity Log Error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Volumes/projects_main/Android/SDK/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.JSch$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.jcraft.jsch.Util$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.vladium.util.exception.ExceptionCommon$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/vladium/app/IAppVersion;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/vladium/emma/AppLoggers;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/vladium/emma/Command;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/vladium/emma/EMMAException;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/vladium/emma/EMMAProperties;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/vladium/emma/EMMARuntimeException;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/vladium/emma/IAppConstants;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/vladium/emma/IAppErrorCodes;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:613)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:605)
    ... 9 more
]
stdout[
processing archive /Volumes/projects_main/Bitbucket/MyWishingWell/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0/libs/./classes.jar...
processing android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.class...
processing android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat$1.class...
processing android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat$AnimatedVectorDrawableCompatState.class...
processing android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat$AnimatedVectorDrawableDelegateState.class...
processing android/support/graphics/drawable/animated/BuildConfig.class...
processing archive /Volumes/projects_main/Bitbucket/MyWishingWell/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.4.0/libs/./classes.jar...
ignored resource .readme
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$LayoutParams.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$NavigationMode.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$OnMenuVisibilityListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$OnNavigationListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Tab.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$TabListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DrawerArrowDrawableToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DrawerToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DummyDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$HoneycombDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$JellybeanMr2Delegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$ToolbarCompatDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb$SetIndicatorInfo.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$4.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$5.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams.class...
processing android/suppor<message truncated>
```

Comment: The issue was duplicated files. Seems like any file in any folder that have the specific extensions like .jar will be recognized even if it is not under the Assets/Plugins folder. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dex format errors happen when their are multiple files that are the same.
Deleting files that are the same will probably resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe those two plugins are some same android .jar, and thus importing them created a duplicate in your Plugins/Android folder.

Check if you have two android-support jars in that folder and delete one.